# Wattage for PPR welding machine?

Tags: plumbing, welding

Looking at some PPR welding machines.  The biggest difference I found was the amount of *wattage*. I’m talking domestic usage (20-32 mm diameters).

I see 800 / 1000 / 1500 watts (and more) ….

Can someone explain where the wattage plays a role? Is that “recovery” time after welding? So the more watts the quicker the welder gets back to temperature?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wattage simply determines how hot and how fast the sockets will heat up. A 800 Watt PPR will take longer to heat up than a 1500 Watt PPR. The 1500 Watt PPR will get much hotter than the 800 Watt one and would be required for larger or multable sockets. You'd have to look at the individual models to determine what wattage would work for you depending on pipe size and frequency of work.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don’t fully understand. I was reading the WAVIN Polyfusion procedures. But all i could find was heatup times (per diameter). Nothing about wattage. Temperature mentioned are 250-270 C. Also looking at the tools all have same diameter sockets, yet wattage differs a lot. I only need to do domestic usage (20-32 mm).

Comment: @Roger The Wavin procedures listed an 800 Watt welder and  in their product catalog. The heat up times are how long the pipes need to be heated before compressing them together. The heater needs to be at the specified temperature before you can apply the heat up times. that's where the wattage comes in... getting the heater up to the desired heat. 250 - 270 C . is a range for normal pipes but some pipes can require 450 C.

Comment: Ah., thanks! I didn’t  realize I could  look at their welder machines. Was lookin at the pipe catalog and installation manual (procedures).